# How to name Settings model properly in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, coding-style, naming-conventions

As we all know the best code style practice to is to name Django models (classes) as singular (`Cat`, `User`, `Permission`, etc.), instead of plural (`Cats`, `Users`, `Permissions`), because it represents the structure of one record of the model. But in case of user settings it become `UserSetting`. Setting could be interpretted as one key-value pair but we have complete user settings record with multiple key-value pairs. So it's `UserSettings`.

It appearently become confusing. So what should we do in that case?

1. `UserSetting`
2. `UserSettings`
3. `UserSettingsRecord`
4. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `UserSettings`, because you should name your model as a single instance of it, since a single instance contains multiple settings the plural is the correct choice (`UserSetting` seems to contain only a single user setting). To distinguish a single instance from multiple instances, you could append the noun instance/row/record, so with `UserSettingsRecord` you could make it more explicit even if I don't see it necessary (the thing is obvious and with long names you only lengthen the code).